# How to use jpg files in Turtle Graphics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I know this might be a duplicate question, and I know that Turtle module supports only gif files, but I really want to use jpg or png in Turtle. I read the source code of turtle.py and tried to modify line 885 and 1132 from

```
if name.lower().endswith(".gif"):
```

to

```
if data.lower().endswith(".gif") or data.lower().endswith(".jpg"):
```

and then I saved the file, but even if I try now

```
screen.addshape("fireball.jpg")
```

it gives me an error:

```
File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 1135, in register_shape
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("Bad arguments for register_shape.\n"
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: Bad arguments for register_shape.
```

What can I do to use jpg files ??? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes up ***so often***, let's write a patch to turtle to allow all that `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage()` can handle:

**patch_turtle_image.py**

```
from turtle import TurtleScreenBase
from PIL import ImageTk

@staticmethod
def _image(filename):
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=filename)

TurtleScreenBase._image = _image

# If all you care about is screen.bgpic(), you can ignore what follows.

from turtle import Shape, TurtleScreen, TurtleGraphicsError
from os.path import isfile

# Methods shouldn't do `if name.lower().endswith(".gif")` but simply pass
# file name along and let it break during image conversion if not supported.

def register_shape(self, name, shape=None):  # call addshape() instead for original behavior
    if shape is None:
        shape = Shape("image", self._image(name))
    elif isinstance(shape, tuple):
        shape = Shape("polygon", shape)

    self._shapes[name] = shape

TurtleScreen.register_shape = register_shape

def __init__(self, type_, data=None):
    self._type = type_

    if type_ == "polygon":
        if isinstance(data, list):
            data = tuple(data)
    elif type_ == "image":
        if isinstance(data, str):
            if isfile(data):
                data = TurtleScreen._image(data) # redefinition of data type
    elif type_ == "compound":
        data = []
    else:
        raise TurtleGraphicsError("There is no shape type %s" % type_)

    self._data = data

Shape.__init__ = __init__
```

Test program:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import patch_turtle_image

screen = Screen()
screen.bgpic('MyBackground.jpg')

screen.register_shape('MyCursor.png')

turtle = Turtle('MyCursor.png')

turtle.forward(100)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really works . Thank you for spending your time and helping me !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) as follow:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("yourpicture.jpg")
im.rotate(180).show()
```